# Unable to fetch the response from Solr server in my web page with Access Control errors

Tags: solr

I have set up a local Solr Server running on port 8983 on windows. Now I'm trying to use HTTP GET request from AJAX to fetch data from the Solr but facing below error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8983/solr/TestCore5/select. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Here is my code snippet:

```
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            url: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/TestCore5/select',
            data: {
                "q": $scope.name,
                "fl": "resourcename",
                "wt": "json",
            }
        })
```

Please suggest how to fix this. Any configurations(`solr-config.xml` or `solr.xml`) can be updated? How?

Comment: You should never expose Solr directly to your users, as that will allow for any user to manipulate the contents of your index freely. Stick it behind a small proxy or service that validates the request and then makes the request back to Solr.

Comment: Hi Mats, Thanks for your response.  Is there also any way where we can set the Header "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'" from solr end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below link helped me to fix the issue:

- https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/03/26/going-cross-origin-with-solr/

Specify the Cross-Origin filters in the web.xml file of your solr package.